# Spring security stateless session not working

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I want to make a secured endpoint of my service to always ask for authentication, on any request. Instead, it only happens once (first time) per user, and then after that no authorization header is required, and it will still work.

I found out that I should set the `SessionCreationPolicy` to **stateless** in order to achieve authentication on any request, so I did that, but the problem is still the same. Only the first time authentication is required, and not after that.

I am sending POST requests from Postman and Restlet Client for Chrome, and the result is always the same.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/reg").permitAll() // public endpoint
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/res/**").permitAll() // public endpoint
        .anyRequest().authenticated() // any other endpoint authenticated
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

How can I make my requests truely stateless?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on github?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Well not really, but what else except the config is relevant? I could post it here.